# AVAssetExportSession exportAsynchronously is very slow

Tags: swift, avplayer, avasset, avkit

Even when I don't apply any filters the performance of AVAssetExportSession exportAsynchronously is very very bad. It takes more than 10 seconds or so to export a 26 second video. How can I fix that?

```swift
let avPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: video)
avVideoComposition = AVVideoComposition(asset: avPlayerItem.asset, applyingCIFiltersWithHandler: { request in
    request.finish(with: request.sourceImage, context: nil)
})
avPlayerItem.videoComposition = avVideoComposition

// -----------

func exportFilterVideo(videoComposition:AVVideoComposition , completion: @escaping
(_ outputURL : NSURL?) -> ()) {
    let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: self, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!
    let croppedOutputFileUrl = URL( fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + NSUUID().uuidString + ".mov")
    exportSession.outputURL = croppedOutputFileUrl
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.mov
    exportSession.videoComposition = videoComposition
    exportSession.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
        guard exportSession.status != .failed else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        if exportSession.status == .completed {
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                completion(croppedOutputFileUrl as NSURL)
            })
        }
        else {
            completion(nil)
        }
    })
}
```

even when I use `AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality` it does not help!

Comment: Have you tried with `AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality` and 
`exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true`?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610146/avassetexportsession-exporting-too-slow

Answer (score 1):

#### First solution:

if you've tried **exportSession** with **AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality** & **AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality** and not helped! then consider **AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality**

[A preset to export a high-quality movie file.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetexportpresethighestquality)

```
let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: self, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!
```

Then try setting the **videoComposition** to **nil** if you do not need to apply any filters , cause as it says in the [videoComposition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetexportsession/1389477-videocomposition)

> videoComposition:
>
> An optional object that provides instructions for how to composite
> frames of video.
>
> The default value is nil.

```
exportSession.videoComposition = nil
```

Try with **.mp4** video encoding formats as it may perform better than **.mov**

```
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4 // or AVFileType.mov
```

And if you need your video to be optimized for network usage then try this

```
exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
```

But please note that this may take a bit longer with the export session!

#### Second solution:

I've experienced the same problem a while ago and I ended up solving this issue by first compressing the video and then apply changes to it which improve the whole speed of the program.

I used the following library

[LightCompressor_iOS](https://github.com/AbedElazizShe/LightCompressor_iOS)

[LightCompressor_example](https://github.com/AbedElazizShe/LightCompressor_iOS_Sample)

and this is a sample code

```
let compression: Compression = videoCompressor.compressVideo(source: url, destination: url, quality: .very_high, keepOriginalResolution: true, progressQueue: .main, progressHandler: nil) { (result) in
    print("Compression result \(result)")
    switch result {
    case .onStart:
        print("onStart")
        break
    case .onSuccess(_):
        print("✅onSuccess✅")
        break
    case .onFailure(_):
        print("❌onFailure❌")
        break
    case .onCancelled:
        print("✅Size after compression is \(Int(videoLocalPath!.fileSizeInMB()))MB✅")
    }
}

compression.cancel = true
```

##### video editor iOS app (just for reference)

You may fetch and run the app from the following project as it is an iOS app for applying filters, stickers and images to videos so that you can recognize how it perform on your device.
[OptiVideoEditor-for-iOS](https://github.com/jaiobs/OptiVideoEditor-for-iOS)

I think the code that you would be interested to read is in the following link

[OptiVideoEditor](https://github.com/jaiobs/OptiVideoEditor-for-iOS/blob/master/VideoEditor/Editor%20Class/OptiVideoEditor.swift)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but the first solution did not work and I don't want to use any third party library to compress every video to basically apply basic filter.